# How to apply a math function to each object of an ArrayList

Tags: java, jgrasp

I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply a math operation to each item of an ArrayList. The ArrayList will be user inputted so there's no telling how many items would be within it. Is there a method that might aid in doing this?

Comment: Foreach loop? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Comment: You can use stream().map to apply a function to each element of a List

Comment: This gives an example of using stream.map() : https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to do? Are the types going to be the same after calculation? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListIterator` -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java
/util/ListIterator.html

Unlike plain `Iterator`, `ListIterator` will allow you to store newly computed value back to the list

```
ArrayList<Integer> source = ...

ListIterator<Integer> iter = source.listIterator();

while( iter.hasNext() )
{
  Integer value = iter.next();

  Integer newValue = Integer.valueOf( value.intValue() * 2 );

  iter.set(newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @puhlen says, in java 8, use stream and lambda expression

```
List liste = new ArrayList<>();
liste.stream().forEach(o->{
    //apply your math on o
});
```

stream provides you many other functionnalities to filter, order, collect... use it if you're on java8

or as @neil-locketz says in java before 8 use a foreach loop

```
 List<type> liste = new ArrayList<>();
for(type o : liste){
    //math on object o here
}
```

Comment: Actually, that code won't do anything whatsoever.

Comment: Your stream code does nothing because there is no terminating method. That is, `map()` isn't called until the terminating method (eg `collect()`, `reduce()` etc) requests the next element. With no terminating method, literally no code will fire.

Comment: sorry, i think forEach and i write map... edited